mysql atomic increment/read to generate unique IDs
I have a table in MySQL 8.0 with an ID and name column, e.g.:



ID
name




7
name1


12
name2


13
name3



I'd like to generate a new ID atomically and assign it to the row with name=name2. I was hoping to do something like:
UPDATE table SET id=MAX(id)+1 WHERE name='name2'

but that's not valid. I read in the MySQL docs that perhaps I can do it with a multi-table UPDATE but it looked complicated and I'm not sure the whole statement (i.e. the part that computes the MAX and the part that updates the id field) would be atomic anyway.
I also need to retrieve the newly generated ID. Specifically I'm calling all of this from Python, so the result of whatever statement or transaction I run should include the newly generated ID so I can use it subsequently in the Python code. I don't want to update the table and then issue a separate SELECT statement to query for the new ID.
Is there a simple way to do this in an atomic fashion, so that many such processes can run simultaneously while keeping the generated IDs unique?
Note that I don't think auto-increment is applicable here. I don't want the newly generated IDs on new (i.e. inserted) rows. I want the generate a new ID and apply it to an existing row.
There are several other questions (e.g. this one) about how to make the above UPDATE statement work with MAX() in it. Please note that this question is not the same at all - I need an atomic way to generate a new unique ID and return it to my code. It's not clear whether that UPDATE statement would even be atomic in the form given by the other answers, and I also don't think its result can be returned to the code. I simply wrote out the UPDATE since it was my first attempt at doing this atomically (e.g. in mongo db something like this is possible).

@ would you mind taking another look? I added a much longer explanation as to why this isn't a duplicate. It's not even asking the same question as the one refernced as a dup, it simply uses the same example SQL query.

See: How can I update an existing record to have a new auto_increment id in MySQL? cc @Shadow since OP's ping to you was incorrect

@AbdulAzizBarkat that question is closer, but note that I need the entire operation to be atomic, and I need it to return the ID to the calling code (i.e. Python in my case) so I can use it for other purposes. All of this needs to work in a highly concurrent environment (hence the atomic requirement). The other questions aren't asking about that specifically, so it's unclear whether their answers would work here. I'm hoping for something that allows as much concurrency as possible (i.e. simpler - ideally no explicit locking, hence my initial attempt at a simple UPDATE).

This would be why sequences exist in database land. I don't believe MySQL has those. So in my experience if you want to solve whatever requirement you want to solve using MySQL... it will need to involve inserts only so auto_increment can be used. Or move to a more capable DBMS which is a head ache and a half.

Gotcha - yeah thanks, I had moved to a table with a single column and I'm using auto_increment. It just feels silly to INSERT data just to get the auto-incremented number. MySQL does provide LAST_INSERT_ID() for this so it's working, I was just hoping for confirmation that I'm not missing something.

To solve this I ended up adding a second table with a single auto-increment ID field.
To obtain a new ID that's guaranteed to be unique I execute INSERT INTO second_table VALUES() and then look at the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() (via cursor.lastrowid in my case since I'm using Python) to read the new ID.
After this I perform a ROLLBACK to avoid accumulating useless rows in the second table (note that it keeps its auto-increment state after ROLLBACK but not after TRUNCATE TABLE!). I looked into it a bit and think that ROLLBACK might (somewhat counter-intuitively at first) be more expensive than committing the transaction when using InnoDB. In my case that was acceptable but for the most performant solution a COMMIT might actually be preferable.
I think the accepted answer is a more direct solution to my question as phrased, but I'm sharing this in case it's helpful to anyone. I think this solution is more efficient in terms of locking so in highly concurrent environments it may be preferable.

Instead of rolling back you could delete the row you just created. DELETE FROM second_table WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Use a transaction to make assigning the ID and retrieving it atomic:
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE table AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxid
    FROM table
) AS t2
SET t1.id = maxid+1
WHERE t1.name = 'name2';

SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE t1.name = 'name2';

COMMIT;


I do think this answer is the right way to do what I'm asking in my question.
For what it's worth I ended up adding a second table with a single auto-increment ID field. Then I INSERT into that table and roll back, and use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the new ID. I don't love having a separate table for it but my understanding is that it will allow for greater concurrency compared to using a transaction. Just mentioning this alternative in case it's helpful to anyone!

You can post that as another answer.

I'm missing a why this would make it atomic. I think a transaction would at best introduce a row lock, so there is absolutely nothing stopping other threads from executing the same logic on a different row at exactly the same time and getting exactly the same maxid. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Wow yeah I'm new to this stuff but it does seem like we'd need to write-lock the table, or maybe use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE with the right isolation level? The latter seems silly because it'll end up locking every row, so the table lock seems better.

@Gimby There should be some transaction isolation level that ensures this works as intended, but I'm not sure precisely which it is. If not, you could use an explicit LOCK TABLE
